# Usage of DKImagePickerController for multiple image selection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Has anyone used DKImagePickerController from the following link to let your app support selection of multiple images?

https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/tree/2.4.3

I don't want to use pods so I simply copied DKCamera and DKImagePickerController into my application project because I want to have it run on iOS 7.0 version as well, but when I put this line of code:

```
let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
```

It gives the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'DKImagePickerController'.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the  **DKImagePickerController**
through cocoapods
Then to use this library import it first like this

`import DKImagePickerController`

now you can use this library without this error